# how to get the 3rd order of each month using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

How can I get the 3rd order of each month?

**order_details**

```
order_id  || customer_name  || order_Date
--------     ------------      ----------
101             rahul          2019-06-12  
102             naveen         2019-07-24
103             naveen         2019-08-03
104             naveen         2019-09-15 
105             rahul          2019-06-27   
106             rahul          2019-08-21
```

This is the output for 3rd order customer make order in each month. I made it for 1st order. But, I couldn't for 3rd order.

The following sql query for finding the 1st order in each month customer level.

**Query**

```sql
SELECT billing_address_full_name, email,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'March' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'April' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'May' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'June' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'July' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'August' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August,
  MIN(CASE WHEN month = 'September' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
FROM ord_details
WHERE email NOT IN (
  SELECT email 
  FROM cus_details 
  WHERE customer_groups = 'internal'
) 
GROUP BY billing_address_full_name, email;
```

**Result**

```
          JUNE  JULY  AUGUST SEPTEMBER
rahul      0      0     1        0
Naveen     0      0     0        1       (Just for example)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't 100% follow your example, but if you want to get the third order of the month for each customer, you can do that with a window function:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT o.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( -- Group by (customer, month)
      PARTITION BY customer_name, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date)
      ORDER BY order_date -- Order rows from oldest to newest
    )
  FROM ord_details o
) src
WHERE RowNum = 3 -- Get third row from each group
```

This doesn't handle the case where there is no "3rd" order of the month.  What do you want to return in that situation?

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: OK.  Let me know if you get it working or have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

**here is the result of it**
    **query**

```
select
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='03' then a.order_id else null end) march,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='04' then a.order_id else null end) april,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='05' then a.order_id else null end) may,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='06' then a.order_id else null end) june,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='07' then a.order_id else null end) july,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='08' then a.order_id else null end) august,
count(case when to_char(a.created_on,'mm')='09' then a.order_id else null end) september
from(
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT o.email,o.created_on, o.order_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( -- Group by (customer, month)
      PARTITION BY email -- Order rows from oldest to newest
      order by created_on
    )
  FROM ord_details o
  where
email NOT IN (
  SELECT email 
  FROM cus_details 
  WHERE customer_groups = 'internal'
)and status!='cancelled'
group by email,created_on,order_id
) src
where row_number=3)a;
```